# Merging two images taking too much time

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I am working on the app where I am suppose to merge the images but when i call the function iteratively, it is taking too much time.Anyone please tell me how to improve the response of the function.

```
- (UIImage *) addImageToImage:(UIImage *)img withImage2:(UIImage *)img2 andRect:(CGRect)cropRect withImageWidth:(int) width
{
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width,40);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

CGPoint pointImg1 = CGPointMake(0,0);
[img drawAtPoint:pointImg1];

CGPoint pointImg2 = cropRect.origin;
[img2 drawAtPoint: pointImg2];

UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return result;
}
```

this function is called in the iteration for 30 to 50 times...So i need to improve the efficiency of it.

Comment: are you merging ~50 images into one or 100 images into 50?

Comment: Yes ... merging n number of images to one image at the end.

Comment: then you should probably pass in an array instead of begin/end context on every one.  Those context-to-image calls tend to be expensive.

Comment: Is `img` or `img2` changing? Do `cropRect` or `width` change?

Comment: yes every parameter is changing each time the function is called.

Comment: @MikeM I did that but due to that memory allocation is increasing which is resulting in increase in live bytes, due to that app is crashing !!

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

1. Cache the results (if images are reused with same parameters)
2. Perform merges concurrently
3. Reuse the context (create the context using `CGBitmapContextCreate` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`)
4. Set the interpolation quality to a lesser value: `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationNone)`

There are some more potential optimizations but they depend on the type of image (alpha, size, type, ...).